# What exactly is memory category "Generated code" in Java?

Tags: java, memory

I am using `jcmd` with `VM.native_memory summary.diff scale=MB` to see why my JVM uses more and more memory over time.
The output is like that:

```
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1541MB +19MB, committed=290MB +45MB


-                 Java Heap (reserved=76MB, committed=48MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=76MB, committed=48MB)

-                     Class (reserved=1093MB +11MB, committed=77MB +11MB)
                            (classes #11008 +980)
                            (malloc=3MB +1MB #22851 +7789)
                            (mmap: reserved=1090MB +10MB, committed=74MB +11MB)

-                    Thread (reserved=43MB +1MB, committed=43MB +1MB)
                            (thread #44 +1)
                            (stack: reserved=43MB +1MB, committed=43MB +1MB)

-                      Code (reserved=251MB +5MB, committed=45MB +30MB)
                            (malloc=7MB +5MB #11790 +7595)
                            (mmap: reserved=244MB, committed=37MB +25MB)

-                        GC (reserved=53MB, committed=52MB)
                            (malloc=18MB #65380 +18712)
                            (mmap: reserved=35MB, committed=34MB)

-                  Internal (reserved=3MB, committed=3MB)
                            (malloc=3MB #20304 +5733)

-                    Symbol (reserved=18MB +1MB, committed=18MB +1MB)
                            (malloc=16MB +1MB #134791 +6616)
                            (arena=2MB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=4MB +1MB, committed=4MB +1MB)
                            (tracking overhead=4MB +1MB)
```

As you can see, the category `code` uses +30MB since I started the JVM. According to  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr022.html#BABHIFJC

this category means *Generated code*.

Unfortunately, I did not find any more details on it. What is "generated code"?

I am using one Annotation in my code which is used very often. Could that be the "generated code"?

Thank you!

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's the JIT compiled code?

Comment: Maybe not the best source of information but [here](https://www.baeldung.com/native-memory-tracking-in-jvm) is Baeldung's post about NMT.  "In order to run JVM bytecode on different platforms, it needs to be converted to machine instructions. The JIT compiler is responsible for this compilation as the program is executed.
When the JVM compiles bytecode to assembly instructions, it stores those instructions in a special non-heap data area called Code Cache."

Comment: Thank you for Baeldung's link, that helps. But there is one thing I do NOT understand: Why does the `code` keep growing? Sure, it has to compile all the suff just-in-time, so ig grows over time. But my app never stopps growing until an OOM occures. So any idea what keeps the code growing and growing and growing? Thank you

Comment: The part starting 'needs' is not correct, and ditto 'it has to compile'. It doesn't. It compiles hotspots, selectively. Any assertion to the contray is false.